# Delete or Vote to Close my own question

Tags: discussion, suggestion

I asked certain questions on SE on which i never got an answer. Moreover i too didn't solve it either so never got a solution for it. So the question remain as it is without use to anyone.

What should i do in this case? Should i delete the question or vote to close it?

Some of the Ref Link are:

1) [How to apply Fixed Special price intead of Percentage Special price in Bundle Product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51756/how-to-apply-fixed-special-price-intead-of-percentage-special-price-in-bundle-pr)

2) [Use SOAP and REST API Together](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39843/use-soap-and-rest-api-together)

Comment: If you are still hoping for an answer leave the open.  If you think the have no value for the future, delete or close them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're the judge. We're not a high-voting culture yet, so just because you haven't seen anyone fave or upvote your question doesn't mean it's not valuable. If there were structural or obvious content issues the questions would have probably been mod'ed by now.

Comment: seems fair. I think the questions are pretty valuable and useful for the future use. I'll keep them open.

Answer (score 5):

If the question is well formulated with enough information to recognize the "requirement" the question will be worthy to keep even if you would never show up again.
SE is very good in the area of self curation, means if your question is useless, it will get removed by either close/delete votes, or simply by voting it far enough down(which causes automatic deletion, if the question is old enough)

As Example, sometimes I post interesting Questions here which are not even important for me, just because I think it is worth to get asked, because there will come the time, someone will search for this.